# Dropbox will not permit me to associate it to any account

Tags: dropbox

I have downloaded Nautilus-Dropbox 2.10.0-2 (64-bit) from the official website and installed it in Ubuntu 16.04. Apparently, the installation worked fine, but now Dropbox's status keeps as "Starting..." (I am not sure if that is the exact term for English version). Also, it will not allow me to access it with any account. I have already reinstalled Dropbox, restarted Nautilus etc but nothing has worked.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: When there are alternatives to a web service such as Dropbox and I have problems with one of them I find it's sometimes easier to just shrug and move onto the next one, such as box.com.

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs. See if Dropbox is giving any errors. On Ubuntu, you would use `journald` like so:

```
journalctl -xu dropbox
```

Another thing worth trying is starting over. Perhaps you installed Dropbox and there was an error, or you missed a step. You can completely remove Dropbox and try installing again. Here is their official un-install instructions:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/uninstall-dropbox